# angular route. state.go not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

app.js

```
.state('page.manage.settings', {
    url: '/manage/settings',
    templateUrl: 'views/managesettings.html',
    controller: 'manageSettingsCtrl'
})
.state('page.manage.settings.currencies', {
    url: '/manage/settings/currencies',
    templateUrl: 'views/managesettingscurrencies.html',
    controller: 'manageSettingsCurrenciesCtrL',
    params: {
        lister: undefined
    }
})
```

manageSettings.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app')
    .controller('manageSettingsCtrl', function($scope, $state, $location) {

        $state.go('page.manage.settings.currencies');

    });
})();
```

Я все ненужное выкосил, оставил саму суть.
Проблема следующаяя - когда мы находимся по урлу /manage/settings и потом срабатывает $state.go в контроллере, переходим по урлу  /manage/settings/manage/settings/currencies , если в ручную забиваю /manage/settings/currencies то - 404
Вопрос чего не получается зайти корреткно по урлу /manage/settings/currencies ?

Comment: как выглядит url который вручную вбиваете? полностью

Comment: все просто - вручную вводился неверный url

Comment: важный вопрос - кто отдает 404 - сервер или ангуляр?

Comment: суть в том 'page.manage.settingscurrencies' по такому стейту переходит а по такому 'page.manage.settings.currencies' - нет

Comment: Ответь на заданные уточняющие вопросы и я смогу точно сказать что именно ты делаешь неверно

Comment: url был такого вида http://localhost:9007/manage/settings/currencies - все было верно с url и не все так просто))

Comment: на самом деле проще некуда: у тебя неверно настроен сервер - поэтому ты получал 404 ошибку при переходе вручную

Comment: ангуляр отдавал 404

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42751/discussion-between-grundy-and-igor-kalamurda).

Answer (score 1):

1 подредактировал урл. Как указал @Grundy "урлы вложенных состояний добавляются к урлам родительских"
2 указал парента

```
.state('page.manage.settings', {
    url: '/manage/settings',
    templateUrl: 'views/managesettings.html',
    controller: 'manageSettingsCtrl'
})

.state('page.manage.settingscurrencies', {
    parent: 'page.manage.settings',
    url: '/currencies',
    templateUrl: 'views/managesettingscurrencies.html',
    controller: 'manageSettingsCurrenciesCtrl',
    onEnter: function() {
        console.log('hello enter');
    }
})
```

Comment: парента можно было не указывать, и он бы взялся из имени состояния  _page.manage.settings.currencies_ -> parent: _page.manage.settings_